# Get value from dynamically created select field within jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

```
$(".controls header").on('click', '.edit-button', this, function(event){
    arrayOfSelects = arry('store the values here, or maybe somewhere else');
    dialog = '';
    // this is where dynamically created html would be added to dialog var
    $(dialog).dialog({
        title: "Editing stuff",
        dialogClass: "someDialog",
        modal: true,
        buttons: {  "Save": function(){ edit(arrayOfSelects, this); },
                    "Cancel": function(){ $(this).dialog("close"); }}
    });
});
```

From the example above, how can I retrieve selected values from x number of dynamically created  elements?

Selecting values from dialog would only provide initial values and not values after user has made changes. Using "someDialog" class doesn't seem like a good idea since the previous dialog doesn't seem to be removed even after it is closed and same dialog is open again. Correct me if I am wrong on either of those statements.

Comment: If `arrayOfSelects` contains the dynamically created elements, you should be able to use `arrayOfSelects[i].val()` or `arrayOfSelects[i].value` (depending on whether they're jQuery objects or DOM elements) to get the selected values.

Comment: Selected value changes on user input, so I don't see how this would work. The array would be static and would not reflect user input changes.

Comment: That's not the way Javascript works. When you use `selectElement.value` it returns the currently selected value, not when it was put into the array.

Comment: That sounds right, will check it out in the morning.

Comment: That was exactly correct, if you add it as an answer I will accept, thanks.